# I get "error: failed linking file resources" - why so?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am an absolute beginner in android development. I'm trying to build a search box. So I have put a searchview widget on my activity. And it gives me this error when I run the app.

```
error: 'searchBoxColor' is incompatible with attribute background (attr) 
reference|color.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

I can't figure out where the error is. Or is there another file I should add to link resources.

This is my color.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3d664a</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
        <color name="backgroundColor">#e1e6e6</color>
        <color name="searchBoxColor">#d6d2d6</color>
</resources>
```

This is my layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:overScrollMode="never"
     android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/backgroundColor" >

         <SearchView
              android:id="@+id/search"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
              android:queryHint="Search Here"
              android:background="searchBoxColor"
              android:padding="6dp" >

              <requestFocus />
          </SearchView>

    </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add color path in background properties

```
android:background="@color/searchBoxColor"
```

it should be

```
 <SearchView
          android:id="@+id/search"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
          android:queryHint="Search Here"
          android:background="@color/searchBoxColor"
          android:padding="6dp" >
```